# Warum ist in diesem Satz "Es" von einem Prädikat in Plural (hervor-rufen) gefolgt?

Tags: verb, pronoun

Ich brauche eine grammatische Erklärung. In einem Satz aus dem Roman "Pfaueninsel" von Thomas Hettche nutzt der Autor das Pronomen "Es" als Subjekt, gefolgt vom Verb "(hervor)rufen" in Plural.

"***Es rufen Orte in uns ganz dieselben Gefühle hervor*** wie Menschen, man vertraut einer Landschaft wie einem Freund, ein Gesicht, das man zum ersten Mal sieht, behagt einem, oder eben auch nicht."

Ich entschuldige mich für die Länge des Satzes, es geht nur um den ersten Stück:

"Es rufen die Orte in uns die Gefühle hervor."

Warum braucht der Autor dieses "Es" überhaupt? Warum einfach nicht "Die Orte in uns rufen..."? Und warum ist "Es" von "ruft" (Prädikat in Singular) nicht gefolgt, oder, alternativ, warum geht ein "Sie" (Subjekt in Plural) dem "rufen" nicht voraus?  Es ist klar, dass "die Orte" das Subjekt sind. Verb soll von Subjekt bestimmt sein, oder nicht?

Danke für Ihre Gedanken im Voraus!

Comment: Die "einfache Version" wäre mMn eher "Orte rufen in uns..." als "Die Orte in uns rufen". Zum einen bezieht sich "in uns" auf das Prädikat (wo rufen Orte etwas hervor?) und nicht auf das Subjekt. Zum anderen geht es um die Kategorie "Orte" allgemein, nicht um "die Orte" (im Unterschied zu "den anderen Orten").

Comment: Es hat jeder Autor seinen eigenen Stil.

Answer (score 5):

Das Wort *es* ist in diesem Satz nicht das Subjekt, sondern *Orte*. Das hast du ja eigentlich schon gemerkt, denn das Verb richtet sich nach dem Subjekt, und hier steht *rufen* (hervor). Der Autor hätte den Satz auch mit *Orte rufen* beginnen kann können, er wollte aber das Verb vor das Subjekt stellen. Das geht, die Reihenfolge ist im Deutschen recht frei. Das Verb muss aber an zweiter Stelle stehen. Steht sonst nichts an erster Stelle, kann man dorthin *es* als Platzhalter stellen. Die folgenden Sätze bedeuten alle das gleiche:

> Die Äpfel fallen vom Baum.
>
> Vom Baum fallen die Äpfel.
>
> Es fallen die Äpfel vom Baum.

Answer (score 2):

Du scheinst anzunehmen, das *Es* ein Singular ist. Nein, ist es nicht.

"Es" stellt einen Verweis auf ein Pronomen oder Nomen dar, das sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural stehen kann. In deinem Fall kündigt "Es" das ins Mittelfeld gerückte Subjekt des Satzes "Orte" an.

Steht das Nomen, auf das verwiesen wird, im Plural, steht auch das Verb im Plural. Genauso steht das Verb im Singular, wenn das Verweisziel im Singular steht.

"Gebraucht" wird das "Es" eben, weil der Autor beschlossen hat, dass er "Orte" im Mittelfeld des Satzes haben will und nicht am Anfang - Vielleicht, weil er die "Orte" näher bei den "Menschen", die den Orten in diesem Satz gegenübergestellt werden, haben wollte.

Comment: Dieses *es* verweist auf nichts. Am besten sieht man das beim unpersönlichen Passiv, wo es gar nichts mehr gibt, auf das verwiesen werden könnte: *Es wurde gelacht und getanzt*.

Comment: Dieses "Es" verweist auf "Orte" - Mit einem anderen Beispiel zu argumentieren beweist erstmal nix. In deinem Beispiel ist "Es" tatsächlich ein Ersatzobjekt. Das ist was anderes.

Comment: Ich sehe den Unterschied nicht.

Comment: @DavidVogt Da ist nicht nur einer. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/es_das_man Fall 2b) Dein Beispiel ist 3d)

Comment: Da steht *kündigt an*, nicht *verweist*. Die Duden-Grammatik (8. Auflage) bespricht das Vorfeld- oder Platzhalter-*es* unter § 1263. Dort finden sich Beispiele mit und ohne Subjekt.

Comment: @DavidVogt Oh, natürlich - du hast recht. "Ankündigen" ist etwas vollkommen anderes als "verweisen" ;)

Comment: *Verweisen* impliziert Koreferenz und damit Kongruenz. Dann muß man natürlich für das Beispiel oben behaupten, daß *es* auf *Orte* verweist, wo das aber doch nur ein Pronomen im Plural kann.

Comment: @DavidVogt "Verweisen" tut nichts anderes als *auf etwas zeigen*. Wenn ich auf etwas zeige, impliziere ich überhaupt nichts. Tut mir leid, deine Argumentation kann ich nicht nachvollziehen.