# Warum braucht es Plural in diesem Passivsatz?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, passive

Ich habe [eine Aufgabe im Internet](https://www.dw.com/de/wirtschaftsf%C3%B6rderung-f%C3%BCr-afrika/l-50371278) gemacht.

In der Aufgabe muss man einen Satz ins Passiv setzen.

> Afrikanische Betriebe stellen Produkte für den eigenen Markt her.

Antwort:

> Von afrikanischen Betrieben werden Produkte für den eigenen Markt hergestellt.

Aber *Von afrikanischen Betrieben* funktioniert so wie *es*. Warum muss es nicht *wird*, sondern *werden* heißen?

Comment: Es wird ein Produkt hergestellt / Es werden zwei Produkte hergestellt. See also here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49859/warum-ist-in-diesem-satz-es-von-einem-pr%c3%a4dikat-in-plural-hervor-rufen-gefolg

Comment: In this construction, *"es" is not a subject!* See the question referenced above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich weiß nicht, was du mit »*Von afrikanischen Betrieben* funktioniert so wie *es*« meinst. Vielleicht dass du stattdessen auch folgendes schreiben kannst?

> *Es* werden Produkte für den eigenen Markt hergestellt

So oder so, das tut nichts zur Sache. Ob es *werden* oder *wird* heißt, richtet sich nach dem Subjekt. Im Originalsatz ist das Subjekt *Afrikanische Betriebe*, steht im Plural und daher muss es *stellen … her* heißen.

Im Passivsatz tauschen Akkusativobjekt (wenn vorhanden) und Subjekt grob gesagt ihre grammatikalischen Rollen. Wenn der Originalsatz also ein Akkusativobjekt hat, wird das im Passivsatz zum Subjekt. Er hat eins, die *Produkte*. Diese werden zum Subjekt, stehen aber auch im Plural. Der Plural der Produkte verlangt also die Pluralform des Verbs:

> *Produkte* werden von afrikanischen Betrieben für den eigenen Markt hergestellt.