# Why "es" with "ranken" when referring to stories and legends?

Tags: word-usage, idiom

I found the following sentences in the DWDS usage database:

> *Es rankt sich ja eine alte Legende um diese Gegend.* (Fünf Freunde 2, 2013)
> *Es ranken sich allerhand Geschichten um ihn.* ("Doctor Who" New Earth, 2006)

It appears that *ranken* is being used as an impersonal verb here, with *es* serving as a placeholder subject. But then why conjugate in the plural in the second example? Would

> *Es **rankt** sich allerhand Geschichten um ihn.*

be correct? If the *Es* is not the subject, then it seems more grammatical to leave it out:

> *Eine alte Legende rankt sich um diese Gegend.*
> *Allerhand Geschichten ranken sich um ihn.*

Comment: Similar, in German: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49859/warum-ist-in-diesem-satz-es-von-einem-pr%c3%a4dikat-in-plural-hervor-rufen-gefolg

Comment: @Carsten S: Thanks. I didn't know using "es" simply for stylistic reasons was allowed; it's certainly very unusual. I think there's more going on here though since both examples are conversational, not literary German. It's seems suspiciously coincidental that this particular (and peculiar) turn of phrase is used twice in the small sample provided by DWDS.

Comment: Grammatically, that’s all there is to it, and it’s not unusual either.  Regarding why this word order is chosen here, maybe it makes the sentence “feel” more like a passive construction (which it isn’t). One does not really envision the legend or stories behaving plant-like. But grammatically this is totally ordinary, even though it has no direct counterpart in English.

Comment: So we'll call it the "pseudo-passive". I think passive makes sense from an English speaker's point of view; it seems more natural to say "Many legends were spawned around the figure," than "The figure spawned many legends." It still seems like an unusual construction though, at least it's first time I recall ever having seen it.

Comment: I suggest to remove the *impersonal-constructions* tag, which dos not seem to apply.

Comment: See also: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33204/what-is-the-function-of-the-es-in-this-sentence https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/48689/es-waren-darunter https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25956/platzhalter-vs-stellvertreter

Comment: @David Vogt: Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first two sentences, "es" is used as a placeholder so that the subject can be in the third position of the sentence. Everything else (like the form of the verb) stays the same.

Therefore, "Es rankt sich allerhand Geschichten um ihn." would not be correct.

While it is true that you could just leave out "es", it usually is part of the sentence for a reason (e.g. because you want to change up the word order a bit or because you want to stress the subject).

Comment: This is helpful; but I'm not convinced it's the whole story. I can understand why something other than the subject might go first as the real "topic" of a sentence, and I've seen how the subject can be put last since it's new information that's important to remember, but I don't know a reason for someone putting the subject in the middle, especially when it seems to be important information. My thinking now is that it's just a peculiarity of phrasing that one uses with this meaning of *ranken*. I'm sure there are many words which have their own quirks of phrasing; perhaps this is one of them.

Comment: @RDBury It's true that stressing the verb by putting it in the middle of the sentence seems a bit odd when you hear about it for the first time. Think about it like that: "Es" works as a "signal" to look out for the important subject.

Comment: @RDBury "Es" can also be used with every verb AFAIK. You can click [here](https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Das_Pronomen_es#:~:text=Wenn%20ein%20Satz%20Subjekt%20ist,meistens%20fakultativ%20im%20Satzinneren%20stehen.&text=Dass%20man%20die%20Pr%C3%BCfung%20besteht%2C,-ist%20schwierig.&text=Zur%20Betonung%20kann%20im%20Hauptsatz%20an%20erster%20Stelle%20das%20Demonstrativpronomen%20das%20stehen.) for more information. It's under the topic "Pseudosubjekt".

Comment: I see what you're saying, there are such constructions in English: "It's true that...", "It so happens that...". I'm not sure it's the simplest explanation in this case, and I think Carsten S's "pseudo-passive" idea seems plausible too. Yes, any verb is possible, but it seems to occur with some verbs more frequently than others; at least typing "es <random verb>" in a search seems not to turn up anything relevant most of the time. But I did find (in *Die Zeit* 18.01.2018) *Es kommt Papageno in Paris.* Thanks for the link; Deutchplus is a useful site in general.